# Android Retrofit parsing one key with 2 data type of values

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

I have response like this :

```
[
    {
        "id":"all",
        "title":"all",
        "logo":"http:\/\/185.118.165.197\/services\/all.png",
        "title_ar":"\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0644",
        "workshop_count":100
    },{
        "id":1,
        "title":"electrical",
        "title_ar":"electrical",
        "logo":"http:\/\/185.118.165.197\/services\/1.png",
        "workshop_count":30
    }
]
```

The problem here is that id is some time String "all" and some time Integer 1,2,.. so what is the best way to handle this multi values of same key?

i am using Retrofit with RxJava

Comment: i know that it's must be solved from Backend but what if i want to handle it from client side is there good way to do that ?

Comment: if you working android with kotlin so you need to Any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your `id` of type `Object` and then handle the response accordingly

Comment: That is worked good , thanks for your help.
i used Any as that i am using Kotlin.